# Searching words and highlighting in Java?

Tags: java, swing, highlight, jeditorpane

I have an `JEditorPane` where in some HTML documents are loaded. I want to add word search facility to this pane like the one which is with Mozilla Firefox. In Firefox, if I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, I (we) get a textbox, to type the word to be searched. Along with this textbox, there are another set of options like Next, Previous, Highlight all and Match case.

I want to have an Hightlight all option along with Match case with the JEditorPane with some background color for the complete word and for all the occurrences of that particular word.

Any guidance?

Comment: So your question is "do it for me"? If not: what did you try? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @JoachimSauer- NO. Dont do it for me. :) Just need guidance on how it could be done- John

Comment: *"Any guidance?"* JavaHelp can fulfill most of that requirement out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These would help:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html

Highlight example : http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/JTextPaneHighlightExample.htm

Comment: @Mob- Thanks for the third link. Don't know how I missed it... ;) - John

Answer (score 1):

Consider to build your appliction on top of the NetBeans Platform (a Swing based RCP). You will get many of the features you mentioned and more for free.

Comment: @Puce- But how to do it using Netbeans..? I am using Netbeans for the same coding... !! - John

Comment: Have a look at the following tutorial: http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-htmleditor.html

Comment: I'm not sure if you get the search funtionality with that tutorial, but if it isn't included it should be easy to add the required plugin.

Comment: @Puce- Thanks for the link. I will give it a try.. :) - John